# jquery get data from another page to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, local-storage

I have two pages index.html and profile.html

[profile.html has user details stored in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr9qa.png).

Now i want to get the data of profile page in index.html with out visiting the profile page. can anyone please let me know if this is possible using jquery

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value");

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem("key");

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem("key");

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage